# EF Core. Универсальный EntityRepository для создания таблиц колонок и отношений во время выполнения

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, рефлексия

Всем добрый день! Стоит задача написать сервис, в котором пользователь сможет сам создавать нужные разделы и справочники под свои нужды.

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется ли возможность используя EF Core создать универсальный репозиторий способный выполнять CRUD операции над entity (тип заранее мы не знаем), а так же создавать таблицы по запросу от пользователя.

Например пользователь на UI захотел создать объект ***Contact*** с полями:

```cs
string Name 
City City
Contact Owner
```

Возможен ли такой подход используя EF Core? Если да был бы признателен за ссылки на статьи, примеры. Если нет, то какой подход лучше использовать для такой задачи.

Comment: Нет, EF не предназначен для создания таблиц/колонок в рантайме, также как и, например, язык C# не предназначен для создания новых типов в рантайме. / Смотрите Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV) или хранение данных в виде XML/JSON в БД.

Comment: Метка `asp.net-core` для чего?

Comment: Вряд ли такую задачу можно решить, просто упростив создание схем данных для конечных пользователей. С учетом того что ORM решает эту задачу для разработчиков, потенциально имеющих более высокую квалификацию, не особо хорошо. Что бы решить такую задачу необходима, по моему мнению, фиксированная схема для хранения произвольных структур данных. В этом случае можно предоставить инструмент обеспечивающий возможность не программисту, инженеру например работать с базой как с конструктором. Это сложно, но я считаю мне это вполне  удалось. https://github.com/firstDismay/pg-conception-builder.